# Accessing a managed bean from a JSP tag file

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I have the following minimal test case:

not_working.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<t:not_working_tag>
  Hello
</t:not_working_tag>
```

WEB-INF/tags/not_working_tag.tag

```
<%@tag description="Main page template" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<html>
<head></head>
  <f:view>
    <h:outputText value="#{userBean.test}"/>
    <jsp:doBody/>
  </f:view>
</html>
```

src/java/UserBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="userBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean
{
  public String getTest() { return "hello!"; }
}
```

Now what I'd expect is that when I access not_working.jsp through the browser, I'd see "hello!". Except what I see is "#{userBean.test}". That is to say, the literal EL expression I put in the value attribute. Now, when I put "${userBean.test}" directly above the , that one works - it shows "hello!". For this simple test case, this would be enough, but of course what I want is to use values from my bean in more complex situations (e.g. in f:selectItems).

What I'm making out of all of this is that the EL for deferred expressions isn't being evaluated for some reason. What am I doing wrong? How do I use deferred expressions, as required in value attributes of JSF tags, from tag files?

I'm using JSF 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2.0) and Tomcat, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score -1):

to display method as a value  you need to specify parenthesis at the end of method name. 
use `<h:outputText value="#{userBean.test()}"/>.` 
Jsp will recognize it as method and will display the value

Answer (score -1):

I have tried the same code of yours its working fine.
See my code as follows

```
package com.mycom.demo;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean
{
    public String myString()
    {
          return "Hello";
    }
}
```

My Html code is as follows

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
<h:outputText value="#{userBean.myString()}" />
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

I have included JSF 2.2.1,jstl jars and tomcat server.
Hope this will solves your problem

Comment: Thanks, but have you tried with a jsp tag too? Your code works for me too, it's when I use a tag file as in my example that it doesn't work.

Comment: I have tried your code, i too got the same problem. I think its the EL problem because jsp and jsf have their ow EL evalutor. T make an unified ELResolver read https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/03/07/unified-jsp-jsf-expression-language.html

Comment: Right I guess it's got something to do with EL being different between the JSP and JSF components used. Piling all sorts of difficult things on top of them to get basic things like this to work doesn't seem like the way to go though. I've switched to using JSF templates and there it works as expected. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

try declaring the variable test, see below it should work....(normaly your managed bean class will have geters and setters)

```
@ManagedBean(name="userBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean{
  public String test = "hello!";

  public String getTest() {
    return test; 
  }
}
```

Comment: The EL is not evaluated at all. If it was and if there was something wrong with setters, you'd get an explicit error.